# Highlight the max number of consecutive positive numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to Highlight the max number of consecutive positive numbers.

[image]

with the help of the following formula, can able to get the max number of consecutive positive numbers. but when tried to be applied as a conditional formula - no luck.

`{=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A20>0,ROW(A2:A20)),IF(A2:A20<=0,ROW(A2:A20))))}`

Comment: For conditional formatting, you must actually identify the cells that contribute to the "run" and think of a boolean (true/false) formula that can be applied to EACH cell in A2:A20 and whose result evaluates to true only if the cell contributed to that run.  Unfortunately, that formula cannot be self-referential.

Comment: Also, your formula is not quite right when your longest run is right at the beginning, because there is no non-positive number to anchor its start.  Try moving A5:A10 to the beginning and everything else below it - you'll see.

Comment: This is a case where it would be easier to write a user-defined function in VBA to return the array of cells/rows that contribute to that run and then write your condition as whether the current cells row number is in that array `=Not(IfError(Match(row(A2),MyUDF(A$2:A$20),0)))`.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a series of 5 positive numbers highlighted and 6 negative numbers highlighted. Are you after just the run of 5 positive numbers highlighted and that's it (otherwise your screenshot doesn't match your problem description).

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie once got some insight; will also also try to make it for -ve case as well. { =MAX (FREQUEENCY (IF(A2:A20<0,ROW(A2:A20)), IF (A2:A20>=0,ROW(A2:A20)))}

Comment: Do you have Excel 365? MIght be able to use Xmatch if so.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe yes, i do have. let me search on Xmatch as well ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you do have Xmatch, you can search both forwards and backwards for the previous and next rows which have a value less than or equal to 0 and compare the difference in the two row numbers to the maximum value of the frequency:

```
=AND((IFERROR(XMATCH(TRUE,A2:A$20<=0,0,1),22-ROW())+ROW()-IFERROR(XMATCH(TRUE,A$1:A1<=0,0,-1),1)-2)
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$20>0,ROW(A$2:A$20)),IF(A$2:A$20<=0,ROW(A$2:A$20)))),A2>0)
```

for the particular case where you are looking at rows 2-20.

[image]